# getting all nodes of the same type

Tags: xml, vba, nodes

I am trying to get the nodes of type erad from a long list of erad nodes found in my xml

Here is my code to get the first erad item

How would i change this to get all the erads from EACH Item. The XML is a regular repeating pattern

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim strUrl As String
Dim strXPathBase As String

Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

strUrl = "https://....XML"

objDoc.async = False
objDoc.Load strUrl

strXPathBase = "//response/responseBody/responseList/item/"
Debug.Print "erad1: " & objDoc.SelectSingleNode(strXPathBase & "erad1").Text


Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate off its parent, `<Item>` and print the child nodes `<erad1>`. Below uses early binding of the MSXML objects:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strXPathBase As String  
    ' ADD VBA REFERENCE: MICROSOFT XML, v6.0 '
    Dim objDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim itemNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim i As Variant

    strUrl = "https://....XML"

    objDoc.async = False
    objDoc.Load strUrl

    strXPathBase = "//response/responseBody/responseList/item"    
    Set itemNode = objDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("strXPathBase")

    For Each i in itemNode
        Debug.Print "erad1: " & i.SelectSingleNode("erad1").Text
    Next i

    Set itemNode = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```